# Expand comma separated columns on two columns while adding NA to repeated values in R

Tags: r

I have the following dataframe:

```
structure(list(A = c("1,2,3", "1,2", "1,4"), B = c("X,Y", "X", 
"X"), ID = c(1, 2, 3), D = c(1, 2, 3)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
-3L))
```

I'm trying to expand A and B but creating NAs so no repeated values are found for columns. So columns A and B should expand "independently", as if the values of A and B are not directly correlated, they are only correlated to ID and D

```
structure(list(A = c("1", "2", "3", "NA", "NA", "1", "2", "NA", 
"1", "4", "NA"), B = c("NA", "NA", "NA", "X", "Y", "NA", "NA", 
"X", "NA", "NA", "X"), ID = c(1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2, 3, 3, 3
), D = c(1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2, 3, 3, 3)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
-11L))
```

None of previous questions about expanding multiple columns that I could find did something similar!

Comment: Use `dput()` to share data, unclear if `1,2,3` are in list columns or are strings.

Comment: Just did. But they are strings, comma separated values

Comment: Are you sure that's the `data.frame` you mean?  That has one column.  Is it supposed to have 4?

Comment: I corrected it!

Comment: It's not clear what should happen to column B.  There are 3 comma-separated items in row 1 column A, but there are only 2 values in row 1 column b.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is a very unusual expansion. You could tackle each column separately and then join them. For example

```
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)
bind_rows(
  separate_longer_delim(select(dd, -B), A, ","), 
  separate_longer_delim(select(dd, -A), B, ",")
) |>
  select(A,B,ID, D) |>
  arrange(ID, D)
#       A    B ID D
# 1     1 <NA>  1 1
# 2     2 <NA>  1 1
# 3     3 <NA>  1 1
# 4  <NA>    X  1 1
# 5  <NA>    Y  1 1
# 6     1 <NA>  2 2
# 7     2 <NA>  2 2
# 8  <NA>    X  2 2
# 9     1 <NA>  3 3
# 10    4 <NA>  3 3
# 11 <NA>    X  3 3
```

Comment: This works like a charm! I was thinking that the only way to do what I wanted was to expand the columns separeted. The Z was a typo, I corrected the structure. I need to do it this way because the information would be repetitive, and the file would be too big.

Comment: What does arrange do in this case?

Comment: It puts things back in sorted order with the IDs increasing. If you don't care about row order you can drop the arrange

Answer (score 1):

In base R, in a `Map` you could `strsplit` *A* and *B*, create `data.frame`s with consecutive *id*s out of it that you `merge`, and `cbind` the rest. Finally `rbind`.

```
with(dat, 
     Map(\(w, x, y, z) merge(data.frame(i=seq_along(w), w), 
                             data.frame(i=seq_along(x) + length(w), x), 
                             all=TRUE)[, -1] |> cbind(y, z) |> setNames(names(dat)), 
              strsplit(A, ','), strsplit(B, ','), ID, D)) |> do.call(what='rbind')
#       A    B ID D
# 1     1 <NA>  1 1
# 2     2 <NA>  1 1
# 3     3 <NA>  1 1
# 4  <NA>    X  1 1
# 5  <NA>    Y  1 1
# 6     1 <NA>  2 2
# 7     2 <NA>  2 2
# 8  <NA>    X  2 2
# 9     1 <NA>  3 3
# 10    4 <NA>  3 3
# 11 <NA>    X  3 3
```

---

*Data*

```
dat <- structure(list(A = c("1,2,3", "1,2", "1,4"), B = c("X,Y", "X", 
"X"), ID = c(1, 2, 3), D = c(1, 2, 3)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
-3L))
```